# Issue with calling function from View in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have created model and view in backbone. It gives me a syntax error as 
"SyntaxError: function statement requires a name - >changeClg: function (height, width) {"

```
selectTable = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var height= 50;
        var width= 56;
        if (true) {
            changeClg(height,width);
        }
        changeClg: function (height, width) {
            console.log("inside changeClg");
        }
        var selector = this.$el.find("select.clg-selection");
        selector.html("<option></option>");
    }
});
```

But it is working when i declare that changeClg function outside of the View with different syntax as below

```
selectTable = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var height= 50;
        var width= 56;
        if (true) {
          changeClg(height,width);
        }
        var selector = this.$el.find("select.clg-selection");
        selector.html("<option></option>");
    }
});
changeClg = function (height, width) {
    console.log("inside changeClg");
    this.$el.find(".clg-dors")[0];
}
```

Actually i need to use el object and also some other objects so i must go to the first option but it is giving me the error.

i just calling "changeClg" function but it is giving me the syntax error.

I would like to know that what is the different between these two function declaration?

Can anyone please tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `changeClg: function (height, width)` is not the correct syntax.
You should be using 
`var changeClg = function (height, width){...}
 instead.

The problem you are facing is since you are not creating an object using a: function is wrong i.e.
`c = {a: function{...}}`
is right and you can use c.a() but
`a: function{...}` is wrong, instead
`var a = function {...}` is the correct way to do it and you can use a() directly

Answer (score 0):

It is working we should use "this" keyword to call object property and also i created "changeClg" function after render property as below

```
selectTable = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
    var height= 50;
    var width= 56;
        if (true) {
          this.changeClg(chartHeight);
        }
      var selector = this.$el.find("select.clg-selection");
      selector.html("<option></option>");
    },
    changeClg: function (height, width) {
        console.log("inside changeClg");
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, to use a method inside a Backbone View you must use this. You will have all the properties and instances of that view inside that method. But it is important that you know that the second option was a private method. So if you don't need to use the properties of view inside that method, to have changeClg outside is not a bad practice. You will have more encapsulation and will be more easy to control your public methods or public api of the view.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your information. Now i understood the difference between these two options.:)